# animation starts with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have writen script which loads content from external php file. i'm using jquery1-9-1. my script works normal, except that moment when i'm clicking on button second time. there is delay for 0.5s before the animation starts. i think i know what is the problem and where is it. `$("#header").animate({marginTop: "10px"...` must execute just on the first click. after this clicked once, it must be deactivated. who knows how to solve it? don judge me so harsh and sorry my english

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var content = $("#content");
    $("#main_menu a").click(function () {
        var id = this.id;
        $("#header").animate({
            marginTop: "10px"
        }, 500, function () {
            $("#content").fadeOut(500, function () {
                $("#content").load(id + ".php")
                $("#content").fadeIn(500)
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to ask, what is the point of caching `content = $("#content")` if you then refuse to use it and just call `$("#content")` repeatedly later?

Anyway, you need a variable to tell if it's the first run or not:

```
    $(function () {
        var content = $("#content"), isfirst = true;
        $("#main_menu a").click(function () {
            var id = this.id,
                reveal = function() {
                    content.fadeOut(500, function () {
                        content.load(id + ".php")
                        content.fadeIn(500)
                    });
                };
            if( isfirst) $("#header").animate({marginTop: "10px"}, 500, reveal);
            else reveal();
            isfirst = false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: works perfect. thanks. it's not all my own code. i'm looking tutorials in different sites and trying to learns JavaScript. So thanks you two times for working script and for advise. accepted and solved

Answer (score 0):

You need to track whether or not it has loaded, in that case. A simple variable and some closure should do it:

```
var isLoaded = false;
$("#main_menu a").click(function () {
          var id = this.id;
          if (!isLoaded) {
              $("#header").animate({
                 marginTop: "10px"
              }, 500);
              isLoaded = true;
          }
          $("#content").fadeOut(500, function () {
          $("#content").load(id + ".php")
          $("#content").fadeIn(500)
       })
  });
```

Comment: That's not what is being asked for.

Comment: Now it is what was being asked for. Sometimes things aren't clear =)